# SDL2 does not render properly after window resize

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I can't draw on the window after increasing its size.
I can still draw on the old part.
For instance, I have a 100x100 window, I increase its size with SDL_SetWindowSize to 200x200.
I can draw to the old 100x100 zone, but the new zone is not usable unless I use a delay before using it.

Here is an example of the problem using SDL_RenderClear:

```
int main(void)
{
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

        SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 100, 100, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        SDL_Renderer *rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

        /* Draw red window */
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(rend);
        SDL_RenderPresent(rend); // Completely red

        SDL_Delay(3000);

        /* Increase window size and draw it green */
        SDL_SetWindowSize(win, 800, 800);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 0, 255,0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(rend);
        SDL_RenderPresent(rend); // Partially green

        SDL_Delay(3000);

        /* Make window blue */
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 0, 0, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(rend);
        SDL_RenderPresent(rend); // Completely blue

        SDL_Delay(3000);

        SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
}
```

This code is supposed to:

- Create a 100x100 window and color it red then waits 3s.
- Increase the window size to 800x800 and color it in green then waits 3s.
- Color the same window in blue then waits 3s.

The code actually does:

- Create a 100x100 window and color it red then waits 3s.
- Increase the window size to 800x800 and color **only a 100x100 square** in green then waits 3s.
- Color the same window in blue then waits 3s.

When I add a 100ms delay before SDL_RenderPresent(), it works properly.
However, I have the same problem on one of my project, and I have to use a 200ms delay for it to work.

Why do I need a delay before rendering?
Is there any way to know how much time to wait before SDL_RenderPresent()?

Comment: Try using an actual `SDL_PollEvent()`/`SDL_WaitEvent()` loop, or at least `SDL_PumpEvents()`; `SDL_Delay()` and hoping for the best is pretty iffy on modern composited windowing systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out your problem!

When you create your window, you need to pass the flag `SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE`. Like this:

```
    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 100, 100, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE );
```

Make this change and your window will behave correctly.

Comment: It worked for me too, but if I move the small window, when the bigger one is created it doesn't have colors (most of the time).

Comment: If this is all you needed to know, please, mark my answer as accepted, otherwise,  I'm waiting for your reply.